# count the specials in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Given an array A (may contain duplicates) of N elements and a positive integer K. The task is to count the number of elements which occurs exactly floor(N/K) times in the array.

i tried to compare the starting element of array with next elements in the array and increment count if they are equal and if count is equal to floor(N/K) then increment the total number of elements which repeat exactly floor(N/K)  times . But i don't get the correct the output. can you please correct me where i'm wrong with my logic.

```
    int countSpecials(int arr[], int sizeof_array, int K){

    int f = floor(sizeof_array/K), count = 1,p=0;


    // Your code here
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof_array;i++){
        if (arr[i]>0)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<sizeof_array;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                count++;
            }
                if (count==f)
               {
                 p++;  
                }
        }

    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The inner loop initialises `int j = j+1`.   That gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Use a hash map.  But that is probably what the question is testing you on -- whether you are familiar with data structures.

Comment: What't the point of `j=j+1`? Maybe you want `j=i+1`?

Comment: thanks for the responses . this is my first question on stack overflow. corrected j=j+1 to j=i+1. but for input array 1 4 1 4 4 1
the Output is: 1    instead of the correct output is 2.   here considered N=6 and k=2 which gives floor (N/K)

Comment: i didn't learn maps and hashing . can you check my code and correct it. 

Comment: @saitejareddy think about what happens after the outer loop sees the first 1 and the inner loop counts all of the 1s, then the outer loop iterates the array until it encounters another 1. You will end up counting 1s you have already counted. Same with the 4s. So, your code is fundamentally flawed since it doesn't ignore values it has already seen. Unless you sort the original array, you will need another array/container to remember values already seen

Comment: @saitejareddy -- You may not have learned about what hashing is, but it is a basic fundamental in solving the problem you presented -- learn what they are.  What you're trying to do now with all of those loops is not the ideal way to even attempt trying to solve this problems.  What if the array had 1000 numbers?  Your loop would iterate 1000000 times!  Also, maps/hash tables are not a C++ thing alone -- it is part of computer science and data structures.  All programmers should know about them and how to use them to solve such problems.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the suggestion and pointing out my mistakes . I'll will solve it using hashing.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::map` to count the number of occurances of each array element, then iterate the `map` checking which items have the count value you are looking for.

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int countSpecials(int arr[], int sizeof_array, int K)
{
    int f = floor(sizeof_array/K);
    std::map<int, int> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof_array; i++)
        m[arr[i]]++;

    return std::count_if(m.begin(), m.end(),
        [=](const std::map<int, int>::value_type &elem){ return (elem.second == f); }
    );
}
```